# Ruby on Rails - Establish Connection to External Database / MySQL Error 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to proxy images from an observium server and updated the `database.yml` as follows (note it's not indented under `production` or `development` as it's the same database and I'd rather not define the same credentials twice):

```
production:
  ..

observium:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: observium
  username: username
  password: password
  host: observium.domain.com
  port: 3306
  wait_timeout: 86400


development:
  ..
```

and then in a brand new class `observium_port.rb`

```
class ObserviumPort < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection :observium

  self.table_name = 'ports'

  def self.get_port(circuit)
    result = ObserviumPort.find(
      :first,
      :conditions => ['port_descr_circuit = ?', circuit.id],
      :order => 'ifName ASC',
      :limit => 1
    )

    return result.port_id
  end

end
```

This is called from a different class simply by `port = ObserviumPort.get_port(circuit).to_s`.

The issue is that this works perfectly fine on my local machine, but on a staging server, I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on 'observium.domain.com' (4)):
```

The strangest thing however, is that connecting from the command line on the staging server works perfectly fine (`mysql -u username -p password -h observium.domain.com`).

I've tried using the ip address to avoid a DNS lookup but the error is still the same.

There was also a slight difference in the mysql2 gem versions but both environments now run the exact same version.

Comment: Does it work if you use your observium server's ip address instead of the domain name?

Comment: Hi @diego.greyrobot, thanks for the suggestion, I shall check that out and post the result.

Comment: Hi @diego.greyrobot, just checked and it's exactly the same error.